# How do I delete items in PandaPower?

Tags: python, pandapower

I just started using pandapower today and I can't find a way to delete items. I don't know python at all, I've tried using `delete()`, `remove()` and `pop()` on all kind of different levels but it hasn't done anything. Is it even possible to delete elements?

Comment: Try typing `help([youritemhere])` to see docs. Or `dir([youritemhere])` to see the methods available to your item

Answer (score 2):

To drop elements delete the row in the dataframe like this:

`net[element].drop(idx_of_element_to_delete, inplace=True)`

For example to drop bus 5:

`net.bus.drop(5, inplace=True)`

Alternatively you can just set an element out of service so that it is ignored:

`net.bus.in_service.at[5] = False`

If you have questions about pandapower you will probably get faster answers on the github repository than on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

I found these [utility functions to modify the topology](https://pandapower.readthedocs.io/en/v2.5.0/toolbox.html#topology-modification), like `drop_buses`, `drop_trafos`, `drop_lines`, etc, which probably don't exist in previous versions.

---

- https://pandapower.readthedocs.io/en/v2.5.0/toolbox.html#topology-modification